# LoginView to tabBarController after login

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

i have an loginViewController which is not in the UITabBarController. This will point at the UITabBarController, when the user is logged in. This works, but when i log out and log in it gives me thread 1: EXEC_BAD_ACCESS error:

When i log in the first time, it goes to the UITabBarController from the appDelegate method and when i press log out it goes to the loginView Correctly, but then gives me the Thread 1 error when i try log in again. What am i doing wrong?

loginView if the user is correctly logged in:

```
-(void)someMethod {
    AppDelegate *appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    UITabBarController *tabBarController = appDelegate.tabBarController;
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:tabBarController animated:YES];
    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES];
}
```

appDelegate UITabBar

```
tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];

MenuViewController *firstTab = [[MenuViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MenuViewController" bundle:nil];
UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:firstTab];


FixtureViewController *secondTab = [[FixtureViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"FixtureViewController" bundle:nil];
UINavigationController *navController2 = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:secondTab];

//WorldCupViewController *thirdTab = [[WorldCupViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"WorldCupViewController" bundle:nil];
//UINavigationController *navController3 = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:thirdTab];

LoginViewController *loginView = [[LoginViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"LoginViewController" bundle:nil];
UINavigationController *navController4 = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:loginView];



self.tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
self.tabBarController.viewControllers = @[navController, navController2];

navController.tabBarItem.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"message-7"];
navController2.tabBarItem.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"football-32"];
   // navController3.tabBarItem.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"trophy-32"];
[[UITabBar appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:110/255.0f green:89/255.0f blue:196/255.0f alpha:1.0f]];

[self.window setRootViewController:navController4];
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

logOut method in the first viewController in the tabBar:

```
- (void)actionLogout

{
Firebase *ref = [[Firebase alloc] initWithUrl:FIREBASE];
FirebaseSimpleLogin *authClient = [[FirebaseSimpleLogin alloc] initWithRef:ref];
[authClient logout];

userinfo = nil;
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = buttonLogin;

LoginViewController *loginViewController = [[LoginViewController alloc] init];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:loginViewController animated:YES];

}
```

Comment: I think the TabBarController should be your app delegates root view controller and the navController4 should be presented modally.

Comment: So in the navController4 make an authentication? if the user is logged in stay if the user is not present navController4?

Comment: This is an option. But you should consider working with models and add a user class which handles authentication code. You could init that class instance in the `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` and decide whether or not to present the navController4.